# Transforming from unstructured to record array with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a record array like this

```
============ rec_data
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
[(269.05515748,   24.71801578) (276.96505874,   21.72957922)
 (198.32475308,   19.26596641) ... (158.11078724,  -49.91437661)
 (219.79342843,  -62.06756014) ( 69.92358315, -166.19385119)]
('rec_data ndim: ', 1)
('         size: ', 206705)
('        shape: ', (206705,))
('        dtype: ', dtype([('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')]))
```

and I change it to an unstructured array with the function

```
arr_data = root_numpy.rec2array(rec_data)
```

so that now it looks like this

```
============ arr_data
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[ 269.05515748   24.71801578]
 [ 276.96505874   21.72957922]
 [ 198.32475308   19.26596641]
 ...
 [ 158.11078724  -49.91437661]
 [ 219.79342843  -62.06756014]
 [  69.92358315 -166.19385119]]
('arr_data ndim: ', 2)
('         size: ', 413410)
('        shape: ', (206705, 2))
('        dtype: ', dtype('float64'))
```

How can I transform 'new_data' back into a record array of exactly the format as rec_data ?

Apologies if my notation and/or terminology is incorrect in some instances as I am still relatively new to numpy arrays.

I have tried

```
new_rec = np.array(new_data, dtype=rec_data.dtype)
```

and

```
new_rec = np.array(new_data, dtype=[('x', np.float64), ('y', np.float64)])
```

but none of these do what I want. 
What would be the most elegant solutions, could you please help?

Comment: np.lib.recfunctions has 2 new conversion functions

Comment: I can confirm that 
```
new_rec = unstructured_to_structured(new_data, dtype=rec_data.dtype)
```
works, but my version of np.lib did not have this.

Comment: There are 2 ways of assigning data to a structured array - as a list of tuples, or doing the assignment field by field.  Many of the `recfunctions` use the field assignment approach.  But if you aren't changing the element dtypes (e.g. all float), a `view(dt)` might do the job, since both arrays can use the same data buffer.

Comment: Thank you, hpaulj! How do you do that, with new_rec=new_data.view(rec_data.dtype) ?